# Is the Lie algebra of vector fields over a circle a simple Lie algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields

I am curious about the structure of the Lie algebras of smooth vector fields over a smooth manifold. I know that they can not be a direct sum of proper subalgebras. I'd like to know if they are simple. Even a piece of example will help.

A simple Lie algebra is a Lie algebra with no nontrivial ideal.

Comment: If $A:=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(f)$ where $f:=x^2+y^2-1$ is the real circle it follows (...) the Lie algebra of vector fields $T_A$ is a free rank one $A$-module on the derivation $D:=-y\partial_x+x\partial_y$ (this must be checked explicitly). Hence $T_A \cong AD$ with Lie product $[uD,vD]:=(uD(v)-vD(u))D$. Then you can check if the "derived series" $...[T_A,T_A] \subseteq T_A$ is trivial or not.

Comment: @hm2020 Thanks for commenting. Are you saying that the subalgebra of real algebraic vector fields is simple? How can I extend the simpleness of the dense subalgebra to the whole algebra of smooth vector fields?

Comment: the Lie algebra of algebraic vector fields has an explicit description in terms of the derivation $D$ given above - this dervation generates the Lie algebra as $A$-module. With this description it should be easy to check if the derived series is trivial. For the Lie algebra $L$ of smooth vector fields you should look for a "similar" description: Is $L$ generated by $D$ as module over the ring of smooth real-valued functions? Is the derived series of $L$ trivial? I believe this type of question has been much studied.